# is there a maximum events in ics files for outlook calendar?

Tags: outlook, icalendar

Im working on a php script that creates a ics file for outlook calendar.
Is there a limmit for the amount of appointments that I put in the ics file?

Can I put a few hundred appointments from the pas or pressent in the file?

Regards,

Ralph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no limit to the number of vevent you can include in an icalendar.

RFC5545 only specifies a minimum number of objects which is embedded in an icalendar.

the only thing you should keep in mind is that the more you put the longer it may take to download.